# PHP "trigger_error" causing fatal exception

Tags: php, drupal-8, php-7.1

In the class \Drupal\Core\Render\Element this line appears, which handles the case of an invalid key in a render array:

```
trigger_error((string)(new FormattableMarkup('"@key" is an invalid render array key', ['@key' => $key])), E_USER_ERROR);
```

On my local dev environment when the condition occurs I get a white screen of death, and a PHP stacktrace in the log. The trigger_error line is the last in the trace. On other servers built by my client's IP guy the error appears in the Drupal watchdog and on the page's messages.

If I temporarily change E_USER_ERROR to E_USER_NOTICE the error is no longer fatal.

So clearly there is some setting somewhere that affects the handling of this error and makes it fatal or not, but I have not been able to find what it is, despite much googling. The Drupal error reporting settings don't affect it.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.constants.php This is like an E_ERROR : *Fatal run-time errors. These indicate errors that can not be recovered from, such as a memory allocation problem. Execution of the script is halted*

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't explain what is happening. In some environments it isn't causing execution to halt.